# Trigger method only selects in Xamarin Forms picker

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to C# and Xamarin Forms. I'm having a picker in my view. I want to trigger and action after user selects a value in picker (actually according to this pic, after user selects done). But what's happening is it's triggering when user hovering an item.
[image]

This is what I tried.

XAML

```
  <local:HCImagePicker x:Name="statusPicker" Margin="0,0,0,10" Image="arrowdown" ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding status}" SelectedIndexChanged="Handle_StatusPickerItemChanged"></local:HCImagePicker>
```

Codebehind

```
     public void Handle_StatusPickerItemChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Picker picker = (Picker)sender;
        Status type = (Status)picker.SelectedItem;

        if (type.status == "A")
        {
            //code goes here
        }
        else if (type.status == "B")
        {
            //code goes here

        }
        else if(type.status == "C"){
    //code goes here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens only on iOS, you can toggle the behavior by applying the Platform specifics.

Quoting from the [Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/consuming/ios#picker_update_mode)

```
<ContentPage ...
         xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core">
    <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <Picker ... Title="Select a monkey" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished">
             ...
        </Picker>
    ...
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```